# Azure Point to Site VPN Connection

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

I am currently setting up the Point to Site azure VPN connection.

I have two vnet A and B without peering

VM A is in vnet A, VM B is in vnet B.

VM A established a point to site vpn connection to vnet B.

In VM A, I am able to RDP to VM B by VM B's private IP.

But in VM B, I am not able to RDP to VM A by VM A's private IP.

That means Point to Site works, but Site to Point does not work.

Did I miss some extra settings? I cannot find any documentation mention the reversed route.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to contain IP addresses in use? As these are private IP addresses (i.e. 10.x.x.x) I assume no leaking here.

Comment: @TorstenS Hi thank you for your reply. We finally found the issue. it is once we need site to access point, we need to use the virtual ip address at point assigned by azure p2s connection.